# How do I discern whether a Type is a static array initializer?

Tags: linq, reflection, c#-3.0

I'll start by saying that I'm working off the assumption that static array initializers are turned into private nested classes by the compiler, usually with names like `__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=12`. As I understand it, having read [this extremely informative article](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/21/how-c-array-initializers-work.aspx), these private classes are value types, and they aren't tagged with the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` class.

I'm working on a project that needs to process certain types and ignore others.

I have to be able to process custom struct types, which, like the generated static array initializer classes, are value types. I must ignore the generated static array initializer classes. I also must ignore enumerations and delegates.

I'm pulling these classes with Linq, like so:

```
var typesToProcess = allTypes.Where(type => !type.IsEnum &&
                                            !type.IsArray &&
                                            !type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate)));
```

I'm fairly sure that the `IsArray` property isn't what I think it is. At any rate, the generated static array initializer class still shows up in the `typesToProcess` Enumerable.

Has anyone else dealt with this? How can I discern the difference between a custom struct and a generated static array initializer class? I could hack it by doing a string comparison of the type name against `__StaticArrayInitTypeSize`, but is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, having just tried it myself with the C# 4 compiler, I got an internal *class* called `<PrivateImplementationDetails>{D1E23401-19BC-4B4E-8CC5-2C6DDEE7B97C}` containing a private nested *struct* called `__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=12`.

The class contained an internal static field of the struct type called `$$method0x6000001-1`. The field itself was decorated with `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`.

The problem is that *all* of this is implementation-specific. It could change in future releases, or it could be different from earlier releases too.

Any member name containing `<`, `>` or `=` is an "unspeakable" name which *will* have been generated by the compiler, so you can view that as a sort of implicit `CompilerGenerated`, if that's any use. (There are any number of *other* uses for such generated types though.)

Comment: A coworker peering over my shoulder commented "wow, you asked a question worthy enough for Jon Skeet to answer?". I will indeed move forward by checking the member name for the Forbidden Characters. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @R.MichaelRogers: LOL. Just be careful if you need to handle *some* compiler-generated types but not all :(